# How do I limit rails route wildcard to 1 directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, wildcard, rails-routing

I'm using Rails 3.2.14 and Ruby 1.9.3. I currently have a wildcard route in my routes.rb file:

```
match  "/*path/" => 'home#index'
```

This allows me to add as many directories after my root and it will still redirect me to my homepage (e.g. myapp.com/a/b/c/d will take me to myapp.com). What I want to do is limit the wildcard to allow just one directory (e.g. myapp.com/a is valid and should take me to myapp.com but myapp.com/a/b should issue an error). How do I go around implementing this?

Comment: Solved it with a regex:

'match  "/*path" => 'home#index',  :path => %r([a-zA-z0-9]*)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a regex:

```
'match "/*path" => 'home#index', :path => %r([a-zA-z0-9]*)'
```